# How can I quickly filter a large dataset?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large data set with global latitudes and longitudes.  However, I am only interested in looking at a specific region, so I want to filter out all lat/lons that are outside of this region. The problem is that I am using if statements to parse the data, however, this takes too long.  Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

The data comes from a netCDF file, and can be stored in a dictionary.  I only want latitudes between 10 degrees N and 80 degrees North, and longitude between -170 degrees and -50 degrees.  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
ret_dict = {}
with Dataset(filename,'r') as fid:
    ret_dict['time'] = fid.variables['timeObs'][:]
    sort_order = np.argsort(ret_dict['time'])
    lat1 = [i for i in fid.variables['latitude'][:][sort_order] if fid.variables['latitude'][:][sort_order] > 10 ]
    lat2 = [i for i in lat1 if lat1 < 80]
```

The above code can be repeated for longitudes.  However, this is too slow with my large amount of data.  It also doesn't give me the indices so that I make sure I keep the original latitude and longitude pairs. How can I quickly truncate the  data for all variables?

EDIT: The answer below is correct for the first part of the question, however I am also trying to truncate other variables using the indices of the filtered latitude.  I am trying:

```
lon = [j for i,(j,i) in zip(fid.variables['longitude'][:],fid.variables['longitude']) if 10<i<80]
```

However I am getting the error: ***TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135885/netcdf4-extract-for-subset-of-lat-lon/35320631#35320631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you need your data sorted? Sorting is an expensive operation `O(nlogn)` whereas filtering is just `O(n)`. If sorting isn't a requirement, you can do it like so with 1 filtering operation. (Keep in mind, I don't know your data, so you may need to modify this a bit)

```
lat = [i for i in fid.variables['latitude'][:] if 10 < i < 80 ]
```

This is the fastest way I can figure with the limited amount of information given. If this is still too long, give more information so that we can try to help you even more :)

EDITED

Comment: I am getting the error: ****ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). I am sorting the data so that the lat/lon pairs remain together.  Is this not necessary?

Comment: I made a sloppy mistake and edited to fix it. Sorry. Also, you most likely do not need to sort so that the pairs remain together. You can verify this on your own.

Comment: I made an edit to further clarify the second part of my question