# How to extract one variable while subsetting .nc files and getting output in .tiff?

Tags: r, tiff, netcdf, clip

I have multiple .nc files at global scale. I want to subset all the .nc files as per lat long extent of my study area and get output in .tiff format.

Spatial extent of study areas are as follows:

(7-12 degree N, 37-44 degree W)

I have written following code in R to subset one file. It is giving me a subset tiff file but with all the variables. My file has 8 variables and I want to choose only 1 variable named as for say 'x'. Could anyone please help me how can I choose the variable named as 'x'?

```
setwd("D:/Data/")

library(terra)    
file = rast("File1.nc")
Extent<-c(37,44, 7,12)
resize<- crop(file,Extent)

writeRaster(resize, filename='File.tif', overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [netcdf4 extract for subset of lat lon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135885/netcdf4-extract-for-subset-of-lat-lon)

Comment: This is a fairly common procedure, with easily found solutions on this website and elsewhere. Can you tell us what you have tried so far and why they did not work?

Comment: @RobertWilson Thanks but that code is in python

Comment: I’m confused now. Have you now asking a totally different question? The title is now misleading

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have reframed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setwd("D:/Data/")

library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(terra)    

setwd("D:/Test")
nc = nc_open("File1.nc")
names(nc$var)
net = raster("File1.nc", varname = "x")
net
extent<-c(37,44,7,12)     #Left Long, RIght Long. Lower Lat, Upper Lat
datasubset<- crop(net,extent)
datasubset
writeRaster(datasubset, filename='Filenew.tif', overwrite=TRUE)
```